# How can I drop a table if it exists in SQL Server 2000?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a DTS package that drops a table then creates it and populates it but sometimes something happens and the package fails after the drop table.  If it's rerun it fails cuz the table hasn't been created yet.

Is there something like "if exists" for SQLServer 2000 like in MySQL?

thanks.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Or quicker:

```
IF OBJECT_ID('temp_ARCHIVE_RECORD_COUNTS') IS NOT NULL  
  DROP TABLE temp_ARCHIVE_RECORD_COUNTS
```

- [OBJECT_ID - MSDN Reference - SQL Server 2000](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa276843%28v=sql.80%29.aspx)
- [OBJECT_ID - MSDN Reference - SQL Server 2008](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190328(v=SQL.100).aspx)

Comment: Although if you have a stored procedure or some other object, this will lead to an SQL error.

Comment: IF you want to verify the object passed to object_id is in fact a user table, there's a 2nd parameter to the function:

IF OBJECT_ID('temp_ARCHIVE_RECORD_COUNTS', 'U') IS NOT NULL  
  DROP TABLE temp_ARCHIVE_RECORD_COUNTS

I believe this was undocumented but worked in 2000, and now is documented.

Comment: IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#Tmp_ARCHIVE_RECORD_COUNTS') IS NOT NULL
        DROP TABLE #Tmp_ARCHIVE_RECORD_COUNTS for temp tables.

Answer (score 10):

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.objects WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'[dbo].[TableName]') AND type in (N'U'))
DROP TABLE TableName;
GO
```

You can check a [list of type definitions in the sys.objects table here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177596.aspx) if you want to check if other objects in your database exist.

Comment: In the question though keng specifically mentioned SQL Server 2000. I thought sys.objects was introduced in SQL Server 2005 and for 2000 you need to use dbo.sysobjects

Comment: @Clive: Did not know that.  I will leave the answer though because many people will find it that are using other SQL Server versions.

Comment: @Brian, sure no worries. We had some issues at work because we had SQL Server 2000 in production but were using SQL Server 2005 in 2000 compatibility mode in development (ahead of upgrading production). By default if you generated scripts from the 2005 database the drop statements used sys.objects, but these scripts then would fail on the 2000 database. Using dbo.sysobjects worked for both 2000 and 2005 versions. 

If you still need to use 2000 I would suggest using dbo.sysobjects, if you are on newer versions then go with sys.objects.

Comment: Found this via Google, but it gives an error for me in SQL Server 2008. I think that either the END shouldn't be there, or else there should be a corresponding BEGIN.

Comment: @Mark: Thanks, fixed.  The `END` was left over from a Create table statement after the drop from my project reference code.

Comment: +1 good solution for 2008, although this question is about 2000

Answer (score 8):

Noone has mentioned this method yet:

```
if exists (select * from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES where TABLE_NAME='MyTable') 
begin 
    drop table MyTable
end
```

This is the most portable method - it works on at least MSSQL2000 up to MSSQL2008.

The INFORMATION_SCHEMA tables are part of the SQL-92 standard.

Answer (score 3):

Sure:

`IF OBJECT_ID('YOURTABLENAME') IS NOT NULL`

where `YOURTABLENAME` is whatever the name of your table is.

If it's a temp table, then just add `tempdb.#` before before the `OBJECT_ID` function call.

Answer (score 3):

One thing to remember when you drop and object and then add back to the database is also add any permissions back to the table. This has tripped us up a number of times.

I up voted TracyNixon's answer. I would say you want to stay away from querying the sysobjects table directly because a Microsoft update could break that kind of code. You isolate yourself from that by using the OBJECT_ID function.

Answer (score 1):

You need to check the [sysobjects](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa260447(SQL.80).aspx) table

Answer (score 1):

The following works, just replace TABLENAME with your table

```
IF EXISTS( SELECT * FROM dbo.sysobjects where id = object_id(N'TABLENAME') AND OBJECTPROPERTY(id, N'IsTable') = 1)
BEGIN
    DROP TABLE TABLENAME
END
```

Comment: Even shorter, skip the call to Sysobjects...

IF OBJECTPROPERTY(object_id(N'TableName'), N'IsTable') = 1
BEGIN
    DROP TABLE TableName
END

Comment: Also, you left out the single-quote after IsTable